# Several errors in older versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, runtime-error

I'm working on a website made in Joomla! It's at http://www.revelation-support.nl/ip-camera.
The website works in all browsers, expect for older versions of Internet Explorer.
Some parts are not shown at all or not shown like they are supposed to and the browsers gives a few errors:

In IE7:

Row 159, symbol 7, Expected identifier, string or number

Row 31, symbol 9, 'localStorage' is undefined

in IE8:

row 48, symbol 2, 'K' is undefined

I hope that fixing these errors is the key to get the website shown correctly.
Can someone please help me?!

Sjoukje

Comment: Notice, that `localStorage` is supported only in IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the javascript from timepicker part of the FormsCrm component. No matter how I look at it, this code snippet makes no sense:

```
K (function(){
K ('#ctime').timepicker({ ampm: true
 });
});
```

It may be that K is declared elsewhere (either in a separate javascript or on the main document), and you've modified something that removed that declaration.

Comment: I usually don't remove any scripts I don't understand. I just change the css and html. Do you think I could remove the snippet of code you've pointed out, or would that only make things worse?

Comment: I don't see any time/datepicker feature on that page, so it is probably safe to remove it. If the source is a system plugin, simply disable the plugin.